# How to cast a pointer to char to a pointer to int

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I want to cast a pointer `pc` which points to char to a point `pi` which points to int

```
char *pc;
int *pi;
pi = (int*)pc                                    // compiler complaint about old-style cast
pi = static_cast<int *>(static_cast<void *>(pc)) // no complaint any more but too complex
```

is there any simpler ways to do this cast and make compiler silence?

Comment: First of all, why are you trying to do this? It's complicated/a warning because it's code smell. Secondly, why are you unhappy with the second version? It works, doesn't it?

Comment: `(int*)pc` is short, but it [hides a hefty conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast). Your compiler is most probably warning you so you aren't caught off guard. When you spell the conversions explicitly, it just assumes you know what you are doing.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? Because accessing such a pointer is (usually) undefined behavior. You usually have to construe a way to always cast the `int*` to a `char*` not the other way round.

Comment: The answer: don't. The less good answer: search. This has been discussed countless times, in particular how a `reinterpret_cast` of pointer types is the same as `static_cast` via `void*`, and how you can't often do anything useful with the resulting pointer anyway. Sure, there are a specific subset of legitimate cases for it, but there's no evidence from your toy example that you have such a case. And without an explanation of *what* you're trying to do, not just *how* you're currently trying to do it, such questions might be doomed to quibbling about the *how* instead of solving the *what* :P

Comment: @underscore_d: Good advice indeed. Me, StoryTeller, M.M and n.m, are still debating the legality. And the final 3 on that list are no charlatans.

Comment: One of the reasons the the `_cast` conversions were introduced into standard C++ in their current form is to make their usage so obvious/blatant/complex that a programmer would prefer not to use them.      The reason a C++ compiler would warn about an old-style cast would be the same.     In such respects, this question demonstrates that both the compiler complaint and the complexity of usage of the `static_cast`s have met their intended purpose.    It's a pretty definite hint of a need to find another (less dangerous) solution to the actual problem (whatever it is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>I want to put the back and forth under [@Bathsheba's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48005212/817643) to rest. So here's an answer about the finer details of what you are doing.</sub>

---

[@Sean already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48005277/817643) you `reinterpret_cast` your pointers instead. And that is equivalent to your second chain of casts. It says as much in [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.reinterpret.cast#7):

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of
>   a different type. When a prvalue `v` of object pointer type is
>   converted to the object pointer type “pointer to cv `T`”, the result is
>   `static_­cast<cv T*>(static_­cast<cv void*>(v))`. [ Note: Converting a
>   prvalue of type “pointer to `T1`” to the type “pointer to `T2`” (where `T1`
>   and `T2` are object types and where the alignment requirements of `T2` are
>   no stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the
>   original pointer value.  — end note ]

Now, let's examine each step of the two step conversion. First we have a `static_cast<void*>`. According to [[conv.ptr]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.ptr#2) (emphasis mine):

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv `T`”, where `T` is an object type, can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv `void`”. **The pointer value
>   is unchanged by this conversion**.

The first conversion doesn't do any alteration to the address. And then it also says in [[basic.compound]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.compound#5):

> A pointer to cv-qualified or cv-unqualified `void` can be used to point
>   to objects of unknown type. Such a pointer shall be able to hold any
>   object pointer. An object of type cv `void*` shall have the same
>   representation and alignment requirements as cv `char*`.

So a `char*` may store any address a `void*` may store. Now it doesn't mean the conversion from `void*` to `char*` is value preserving, only that they can represent the same values. Now, assuming a very restricted use case, that is enough of a guarantee. But there's more at [[expr.static.cast]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.static.cast#13):

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 void” can be converted to a prvalue
>   of type “pointer to cv2 T”, where T is an object type and cv2 is the
>   same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1. If
>   the original pointer value represents the address A of a byte in
>   memory and A does not satisfy the alignment requirement of T, then the
>   resulting pointer value is unspecified. Otherwise, if the original
>   pointer value points to an object a, and there is an object b of type
>   T (ignoring cv-qualification) that is pointer-interconvertible with a,
>   the result is a pointer to b. **Otherwise, the pointer value is
>   unchanged by the conversion**.

Where am I going with this? Assuming `pc` already holds the address of an `int` (suitably converted according to the above), then casting the `char*` to an `int*` via `reinterpret_cast` will give you the address of the original `int`. The note under the first paragraph says as much, and the further quotes prove it. If it doesn't hold the address of an `int`, you are playing roulette and are likely going to lose. Your program has undefined behavior. You should follow Bathsheba's advice to the letter.

Comment: thanks for your explanation,I’m a new programmer and find the compiler complaining about the old-style cast in a old project.I thought it might be a better way to do this and I came here...I did have much to learn.

Answer (score 7):

The behaviour on converting, in general, a `char*` pointer to an `int*` pointer is *undefined*. Dereferencing such a pointer will cause you further trouble as you will be breaking *strict aliasing* rules. Note that the C++ Standard does not require `sizeof(char*)` to be the same as `sizeof(int*)`.

(Note that converting an `unsigned char*` pointer to an `int*` is well-defined if the `unsigned char*` pointer actually points to an `int`).

Don't do it. Ever.

Comment: Are you sure? `unsigned char*` is certainly OK.

Comment: @Bathsheba - Accessing the memory is one thing (and I would prefer `unsigned char` to be on the safe side). But just obtaining a pointer and casting back seems legit.

Comment: Perhaps it's one to study more carefully. Do bear in mind the potential for 1's complement and signed magnitude `char` prior to C++14.

Comment: I don't deny that the possibility of filling that integer with an indeterminate value is on the table. But you are very wrong to say that the pointer conversion itself is the undefined behavior.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get it. Why is converting a `char*` to an `int*` undefined? Let's say the char* points to a well defined `char` buffer, which is part of a self-created container<int>. Is it undefined to e.g. `T& operator [] ( size_t _idx ) { return *( reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_buffer + _idx * sizeof(T)) ); }`? I'd be happy about further explanation.

Comment: You should use an unsigned char array as your buffer. And in general you might be breaking alignment requirements for `T`, although that problem manifests itself when dereferencing the pointer, not setting it (I think).

Comment: Pointer casting never violates the strict aliasing rule. The rule is about accessing an object of one type via lvalue of a different type.

Comment: It's not undefined to do the cast either. At worst, result is unspecified if the alignment is not correct.

Comment: @M.M On that point we will have to agree to disagree, at least for now. I believe that a cast from char* to int* in general is UB, along similar lines to something like `int s; int* t = &s + 2;` is UB. Note that the rules are stricter in C++ than they are in C.

Comment: `&s + 2` is UB for forming  a pointer outside of bounds of any object. But if the source pointer points to an object, then the result of casting it still points to the same storage (or unspecified if misaligned)

Comment: @M.M But what if an `int*` pointer is *smaller* than the `char*` pointer? Unrealistic indeed for `int*`, but more feasible with a `double*`.

Comment: Any character type is OK, signed unsigned or plain.

Comment: *what if an `int*` pointer is smaller than the `char*` pointer* Then what will happen is exacly the same thing that happens when casting `void*` to `int*` or `unsigned char*` to `int*`.

Comment: The pointer sizes must be such that the behaviour required by the standard can be implemented. The standard explicitly allows converting between pointers to different object types.

Comment: @Bathsheba You also diverge from the standard then, since the standard says this is allowed

Comment: @M.M Well a mince pie and a glass of port would certainly be due to the chap who submits an answer backed up with appropriate standard references.

Comment: @Bathsheba the answer by Sean is correct and links to cppreference which follows the standard closely (see point 5 on that page for this case).  You're claiming UB for some reason - the onus is on you to provide support for your claim

Comment: @M.M I'd prefer an assignment to `nullptr` rather than to 0, and that answer presents a *very* specific case. I still maintain my answer as it stands is correct; certainly in C++.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Happy New Year to you and the sock bots.

Comment: And to you as well! :)

Answer (score 7):

If you really need to do this then [reinterpret_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) is your friend:

```
char *pc = 0;
int *pi = 0;

pi = reinterpret_cast<int*>(pc);
```

Comment: First 7 words being the most important.

Comment: @Sean - I agree with Rotem's comment.   You really need to highlight the first seven words.   There are VERY few real-world circumstances where `reinterpret_cast` is a preferred solution, due to likelihood of subsequent instances of undefined behaviour.