# reinterpret_cast and explicit alignment requirement

Tags: c++, alignment, reinterpret-cast

Given this (bold part) about `reinterpret_cast`, I was expecting that the piece of code below would generate different addresses when casting `X*` to `Y*` since the latter is more striclty aligned than the former. What am I missing here?

> Any object pointer type T1* can be converted to another object pointer type cv T2*. This is exactly equivalent to static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(expression)) (**which implies that if T2's alignment requirement is not stricter than T1's, the value of the pointer does not change** and conversion of the resulting pointer back to its original type yields the original value)

[cppreference/reinterpret_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)

```
#include <iostream>


struct alignas (1) X
{
    char c;
};


struct  alignas (32) Y
{
    char c;
};

int main(int argc, const char *const* const argv)
{
    std::cout << alignof(X) << " " << alignof(Y) << std::endl;

    X x;
    Y y;
    std::cout << &x << " " << reinterpret_cast<Y*>(&x) << std::endl;
    std::cout << &y << " " << reinterpret_cast<X*>(&y) << std::endl;

}
```

**output**

```
Program returned: 0
1 32
0x7ffef3434578 0x7ffef3434578
0x7ffef3434540 0x7ffef3434540
```

[snippet on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PYMYj4cGW)

Comment: "if a then b" does not imply "if not a then not b"

Comment: From `static_cast` reference: _"If the original pointer value represents an address of a byte in memory that does not satisfy the alignment requirement of the target type, then the resulting pointer value is **unspecified**."_ I believe this rule applies here. See 10) in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast. C++ standard (draft) link: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#13.sentence-2.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thanks for the generic answer. I was expecting something from the standard that gives more context.

Comment: Reinterpret cast never change binary value of pointer. It only rrinterpret it type

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks! I guess then that if we put together the fact that ``reinterpret_cast`` is just
``static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(expression))`` then that means that the resulting pointer in case of going to strict alignment is not specified!

Comment: @RbMm The quote in the question doesn't agree.

Comment: Relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48008932/580083.

Comment: Thanks @DanielLangr! Can you put your first comment as an answer together with  this ``static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(expression))`` fact?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat and you can build example where `reinterpret_cast<Y*>(p)` return different binary value than `p` ?

Comment: @RbMm - Don't be a silly goose who hangs on to *their* implementation of C++ and thinks it reflects about *all* possible implementations. That's a false induction and is a known fallacy.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica - reinterpret_cast<T*> will be semantically wrong if pointer not really point to  T object, but i think by design this type of cast must never change binary value, unlike static cast for instance

Comment: @RbMm - The design is quoted bellow and says quite clearly that it may do whatever with the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#7):

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type. When a prvalue `v` of object pointer type is converted to the object pointer type “pointer to cv `T`”, the result is `static_­cast<cv T*>(static_­cast<cv void*>(v))`.

Then, from [[expr.static.cast]/13](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#13):

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 `void`” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 `T`”, where `T` is an object type and cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1. **If the original pointer value represents the address A of a byte in memory and A does not satisfy the alignment requirement of T, then the resulting pointer value is unspecified**....

I believe these rules apply here. In your case, `reinterpret_cast<Y*>(&x)` is resolved as `static_cast<Y*>(static_cast<void*>(&x))`. The *original pointer value* `static_cast<void*>(&x)` represents the address A and this address generally does not satisfy the alignment requirements of `Y`.
Consequently, the value of the resulting pointer is **unspecified**.

Comment: Great answer. Is this quote ([expr.reinterpret.cast]/7) applied on function pointer also?